# Create a local setup from a published .Net MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, local

I have a web application developed in .Net MVC those build files are sitting in a server. I want to create a local setup for the application. In the server, there is no .cs files since it has been build to dll. Is there any way to create a local setup from the build application? Thanks

Comment: Since the project file already compiled to DLL (class library), you need certain tool that able to translate IL code to source code. From the given source code, you can create new local project and build similar project structure like the server has, except for certain configurations which should modified by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JetBrains dotPeek to decompile source and generate project from dll.

[image]

This will generate the web application with all the decompiled source files.